# Toggle Class while removing class from siblings on owl carousel drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I tried changing in a condition statement but it did not work. The question is as follows.

**How to toggle the active class while removing the class from siblings on owl carousel drag?**

```html
<div id="resource-hashes">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" id="resource-link" class="active">
      <span>Startup Resources</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" id="business-link">
      <span>Business Resources</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
var owl = $('#resources');
owl.owlCarousel();

//custom buttons on click actions
owl.on('dragged.owl.carousel', function() {
  $('#resource-hashes .container > a').removeClass('active').siblings().toggleClass('active');
});
```